# How do I get list of all types in Maya's ls command?

Tags: python, maya, mel, pymel

In Maya there is a ls command which lists all objects in a scene (or DAG).

```
pm.ls()
```

[Here is](https://help.autodesk.com/cloudhelp/2017/ENU/Maya-Tech-Docs/PyMel/generated/functions/pymel.core.general/pymel.core.general.ls.html?highlight=ls#pymel-core-general-ls) reference to `ls` command.

We can list specific type of element by passing `type` parameter.

```
pm.ls(type="joint")
```

Some possible types are, *camera*, *mesh*, *joint* etc.

My question is what are all types available to ls() command? Documentation doesn't help much. Where do I find it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the flag to query node types :

```
cmds.ls(nt=True)
```

Comment: Long argument name: `cmds.ls(nodeTypes=True)`. Documentation states _“Lists all registered node types.”_